# Classloading sequence of class variable when initializing class variable

Tags: java, class, variables, static

When i run this program, it appears that sometimes **55** will be printed out, although i am certain that **6** is the correct behavior.

Or could it be that i was seeing wrong?

```
public class Test {
    static int a = 55;

    static {
        a = 6;
    }

    public static void main(String abc[]){
        // a is 6
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I think Cularis got it right, when i shifted the order of the static block and the instantiation and initialization, 55 is printed. It is indeed in texture order.

```
public class Test {
    static {
        a = 6;
    }

    static int a = 55;

    public static void main(String abc[]) {
        // a is 55
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chin, AFAICT, cularis and trashgod concur that you need your eyes examined - you did __not__ see a 55 ;-).

Comment: The only way (i can think of) this to happen is to use pre java 5 JVM that does class loading in separate thread or your JVM has a bug.

Comment: In general,`System.out.println()` is not a reliable way to determine whether one thing [*happens before*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#44670), especially

> 12.4.2 Detailed Initialization Procedure
>
> ... Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static
>   initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface,
>   **in textual order**, as though they were a single block, except that
>   final class variables and fields of interfaces whose values are
>   compile-time constants are initialized first (§8.3.2.1, §9.3.1,
>   §13.4.9). ...

Comment: I don't see how this explains what Chin Boon is seeing.  Can you explain?

Comment: It does explain what should happen and that 55 should not happen.